# adding a key-value pair to inner array

Tags: php

I already have data in array as

```
 $a = array (
     [2011-07-09] => array(['new'] => 12),
     [2011-07-10] => array(['new'] => 15)
 );
```

Now I want to add another key-value pair to inner array so that output will be like

```
 $a = array (
     [2011-07-09] => array(['new'] => 12, ['recurring'] => 52),
     [2011-07-10] => array(['new'] => 15, ['recurring'] => 80)
 );
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a['2011-07-09']['recurring'] = 52;
$a['2011-07-10']['recurring'] = 80;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you plan to implement the `recurring` key, this will do:

```
$a['2011-07-09']['recurring'] = 52;
$a['2011-07-10']['recurring'] = 80;
```